# Associated type binding not allowed in lazy_static Rust

Tags: rust

I'd like to create a `HashMap` with [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/), but can't seem to provide the right type arguments:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref DROPPABLES: Mutex<HashMap<String, D: DroppableExt>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}
pub trait DroppableExt: DynClone+Send{
    fn droppable_id(&self)->String; 
}
```

gives error:

```
error[E0229]: associated type bindings are not allowed here
  --> src\main.rs:56:54
   |
56 |     static ref NEW_DROPPABLES: Mutex<HashMap<String, D: DroppableExt>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new()) ;
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ associated type not allowed here
```

What am I doing wrong here? I just want require that all the HashMap values have a type with implements `DroppableExt`.

Comment: A single HashMap can't store values of different types. You probably can use `Box<dyn DroppableExt>`, if the dynamic dispatch and the inability to do anything not described by the trait suits you.

Comment: Can you define such a hashmap _without_ `lazy_static`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd get the same error if you tried to do this

```rust
fn main() {
    let DROPPABLES: Mutex<HashMap<String, D: DroppableExt>>;
}
```

so this has nothing to do with `lazy_static`. If you want `DROPPABLES` to handle values of different types as long as they implement `DroppableExt`, you can use [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html):

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref DROPPABLES: Mutex<HashMap<String, Box<dyn DroppableExt>>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
    //                                           ^^^
    // note that you'll have to box anything you want to store in DROPPABLES now
}
pub trait DroppableExt: DynClone+Send{
    fn droppable_id(&self)->String; 
}
```